# CALayer hitTest with sublayers

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, calayer, hittest

I have a structure composed on a root layer and 2 CALayer subclass. These 2 layers contain a layer too.

Here a scheme:

```
ROOT LAYER 
    |
    |------- LAYER A
    |           |---------BG
    |
    |
    |--------LAYER B
                |---------BG
```

If I call the `hitTest` method on the `ROOT LAYER` it returns the most inner layer into the hierarchy. So if user clicks over `LAYER A` I get the `BG` of `LAYER A`.

```
//In this example hitResult will contains the BG of LAYER A or the BG of LAYER B
CALayer *hitResult = [rootLayer hitTest:point)];
```

How can I stop the responder chain and get directly `LAYER A` or `LAYER B` from a HitTest sent to `ROOT LAYER` ?

Comment: If the layers are your own subclasses then you can override `hitTest:` and do your own thing.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I can't understand. How can I stop the propagation with the subclass?

Comment: Return `NO` from the background layers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these layers are your own CALayer subclasses then you can override `hitTest:` or `containsPoint:` to do your own logic there.

Overriding `containsPoint:` and returning `NO` in your background layers will stop them from being returned from their superlayers `hitTest:` implementation.

Alternatively you could override `hitTest:` in Layer A and Layer B and return `self` if they contain the point.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, note that if you set a null z scale, layers don't pass the hit test anymore.

```
// BG layer won't receive clicks
bgLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 0)
```

It can be a way to make layers inactive without subclassing, but I guess Apple is free to change this behaviour anytime, so I won't recommend it.

I drop this answer anyway for those who may wonder why sublayers don't get clicks anymore. Just get sure you pass 1 in sz in any scaling.

I have myself lost few hours with this tricky one.